# UITableView indexPathForSelectedRow return 0 (incorrect value)

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to make an upcoming events table in my app but when I select a row indexPathForSelectedRow always returns 0.

```
NSArray *upcommingTitle;
NSMutableArray *upcommingSubtitle;
NSMutableArray *upcommingTime;

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)datesTable numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return upcommingTitle.count;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)datesTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    DatesCustomCell *Cell = [datesTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(!Cell)
    {
        Cell = [[DatesCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    Cell.DatesTitle.text = [upcommingTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Cell.DatesSubtitle.text = [upcommingSubtitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Cell.DatesTime.text = [upcommingTime objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return Cell;
}

self.datesTable.dataSource = self;
self.datesTable.delegate = self;
```

View Did Load

```
upcommingTitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Title1", @"Title2", nil];
upcommingSubtitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Sub1", @"Sub2", nil];
upcommingTime = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Date1", @"Date2", nil];
```

But the following always returns 0 resulting in the "test" label to be "Title1"

View Did Appear

```
_test.text = [upcommingTitle objectAtIndex:self.datesTable.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
```

Thanks for you help

Comment: update your query with didselect delegate method.

Comment: I'm really sorry but i'm new with iPhone app dev could you please explain that more or give me an example? Thanks @Ganapathy

Comment: You question is not clear. Explain clearly then only you can get any help.

Comment: When I select a cell the app is should push another view on the screen with a label saying the _upcommingTitle_ for the cell you selected, I have used this code `_test.text = [upcommingTitle objectAtIndex:self.datesTable.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];` to do this but the label always reads _Title1_. @Ganapathy

Comment: After selection of the particular cell only indexPathForSelectedRow returns the selected row of indexpath. So that in your viewDidAppear it will always returs Title1

Comment: where you have written this code? Inside your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: Yeah... I'm just beginning programming so im slightly confused, how do you suggest doing it? Thanks @wesley

Comment: `_test.text = [upcommingTitle objectAtIndex:self.datesTable.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];` was written inside ViewWillAppear. @wesley

Comment: thats why i told you, in your viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear indexPathForSelectedRow will return only 0.

Comment: When you select a cell the app is should push another view on the screen with a label right? Where you written the code for pushing another view?

Comment: Both views are connected to the same subclass.

Comment: So... I put the code in:
`-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)datesTable didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _test.text = [upcommingTitle objectAtIndex:self.datesTable.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
}`

Comment: But the label didn't change at all...

Comment: Where you have selected any row in the tableView?? If you haven not selected any row then it will always come Zero

Comment: [here is my .m file](http://nytrex.webs.com/code.doc)

Comment: My .h is
`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DatesNewViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *datesTable;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segCont;
- (IBAction)segCont:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *upcommingView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *timetableView;

- (IBAction)swipeRight:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)swipeLeft:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *test;`

Comment: I must go now but il work on this app tomorrow thanks for your help @wesley

Comment: Are you allowing multiple selection? If you have more than one cell selected and ask for indexPathForSelectedRow instead of indexPathsForSelectedRows, you will have the lowest selected index path.
You should enable single selection mode (allowsMultipleSelection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to push your another view in your didSelect method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Here, indexpath returns the selection of cell's indexpath, so put your code here

_test.text = [upcommingTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//then push your view 

}
```

UPDATED : then use this code

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"pushView"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
        PushingViewController *pushView = [segue destinationViewController];
        pushView._test.text = [upcommingTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
}
```

Comment: I was pushing to the other view via storyboards (linking) does this mean I have to push the view programmatically?

Comment: @JohannBurgess check with my updated answer or atleast show your prepareForSegue method?

Comment: Here is my prepareForSegue method
`-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"pushView"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.datesTable indexPathForCell:sender];
        DatesNewViewController *pushView = [segue destinationViewController];
        pushView.test.text = [upcommingTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        
    }
}
`
It still doesn't update the text feild (**_test**). Remember they are both connected to _DatesNewViewContoller_

Comment: Both view are connected to the same subclass (.h & .m file) [Here](http://nytrex.webs.com/code.doc) is my .m file.

Answer (score 0):

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)datesTable didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
_test.text = [upcommingTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
}

Just put this code in your application.
```

Comment: you got the data in tableview ?

Comment: Yes. Both the table view and the pushed view are connected to the same subclass does that effect it?

Comment: _test is in the view being pushed on screen

Comment: simple think is that you got value in _test.text, when ever you select row in table view you definitely get the value...

Comment: `(void)tableView:(UITableView *)datesTable didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
_test.text = [upcommingTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
}` Does not change **_label**
But when `_test.text = [upcommingTitle objectAtIndex:self.datesTable.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];` was in _ViewWillLoad_ it changed **_label** but only to the first item in the table. [This](http://d2bm3ljpacyxu8.cloudfront.net/fit/105x97/http://nytrex.webs.com/Capturexcode.PNG) is what that section of the storyboard looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to deselect cell before presenting your seque

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //Call This Line
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowMobileShopStore" sender:nil];
    //Before This
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:true];        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The initial question was: indexPathForSelectedRow return 0 (incorrect value),

Well, this is by-design, from the apple developer notes, the value returns an the IndexPath which can be NULL (is what you are seeing).

So, to do things right:

1) You need to test if the indexPathForSelectedRow is NOT NULL first

2) If it's not NULL then it would contain (.row) which would then give you the selected row-index, this starts from 0.

3) Please note that indexPathForSelectedRow.row would return ZERO in the case of indexPathForSelectedRow is NULL.

Here is the code that I've tested and works:

```
if (MyTableViewList.indexPathForSelectedRow)
{
   long SelectedRow = MyTableViewList.indexPathForSelectedRow.row;
}
```

I hope this helps,